# How do I create a view to re-arrange blocks or menu items?

Tags: views, routes

I would like to create an admin view that allows to reorder menu items. I know it is a standard admin feature, but I would like to display it in a panel.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [draggableviews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) to reorder the items.